# Longest strings from list

Tags: python

I was making a function that returns the longest string value from a list. My code works when there is only one string with the most characters. I tried to make it print all of the longest strings if there were more than one, and I do not want them to be repeated. When I run this, it only returns 'hello', while I want it to return 'ohman' and 'yoloo' also. I feel like the problem is in the line `if item not list:`, but I have tried everything and it doesn't work.

```
list = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey','ohman', 'yoloo', 'hello']
def length(lists):
    a = 0 
    answer = ''
    for item in lists:
        x = len(item) 
    if x > a:
        a = x
        answer = item
    elif x == a:
        if item not in list:
            answer = answer + ' ' + item
    return answer
print length(list)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**First**, we can find the maximum length of any string in the list:

```
stringlist = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey','ohman', 'yoloo', 'hello']
#maxlength = max([len(s) for s in stringlist])
maxlength = max(len(s) for s in stringlist)  # omitting the brackets causes max 
                                             # to operate on an iterable, instead
                                             # of first constructing a full list
                                             # in memory, which is more efficient
```

A little explanation. This is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which allows you to *comprehend* one list as another list. The code  `[len(s) for s in stringlist]` means "generate a list-like object, by taking `stringlist`, and for every `s` in that list, give me instead, `len(s)` (the length of that string).

So now we have a list `[2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5]`.  Then we call the built-in [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function on that, which will return `5`.

**Now** that you have the max length, you can filter the original list:

```
longest_strings = [s for s in stringlist if len(s) == maxlength]
```

This does just as it reads in english:  "For each string `s` in stringlist, give me that string `s`, if `len(s)` is equal to `maxlength`."

**Finally**, if you want to make the result unique, you can use the [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) constuctor to generate a unique set:

```
unique_longest_strings = list(set(longest_strings))
```

(We are calling `list()` to turn it back into a list after removing the duplicates.)

---

This boils down to:

```
ml = max(len(s) for s in stringlist)
result = list(set(s for s in stringlist if len(s) == ml))
```

---

*Note*: Don't use a variable named `list`, as it overrides the meaning of the name for the `list` type.

Comment: I think the OP wants all strings that have the maximum length, not the maximum length among all strings.

Comment: Just add `[s for s in stringlist if len(s) == maxlength]` to the end and you're golden

Comment: i want it to also return the actual string(s)

Comment: @JoshSmeaton - Thank you. I was in the middle of writing that when you commented :-)

Comment: It returns 2 of the same values

Comment: You can use `set()` to generate a unique set from possibly duplicate input values.

Comment: @user1816640 then you should have mentioned you needed distinct values. Wrap the final answer like so: `list(set(longest_strings))`

Comment: to return the actual string, you could just do `stringlist[stringlist.index(maxlength)]` or something similar.

Comment: @ITNinja `maxlength` is an integer (the maximum length). You're not going to find anything passing that to `index()` of the list of strings.

Comment: You could do `maxlength = max(len(s) for s in stringlist)` instead which is probably more memory efficient.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I had that in my final two-liner, but have now edited the first example as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Its not actually a list comprehension. It is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 12):

I highly endorse Jonathon Reinhart's answer, but I just couldn't hold it... How about this?

```
max(map(len, stringlist))
```

There is no need to write a list comprehension, this is even simpler...

Comment: Thank you. This is still a one-liner, and only for the maximum length part.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, that is why I said that I highly endorse yours... I just wanted to compare this specific section of code... don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: It's nice to see the use of `map` in comparison, though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Then edit your answer so I can delete mine... Nobody answered when I commented your post

Comment: Nah, this is fine. I don't want to have too much stuff in there, and yours is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have miswrote the line `if item not in list:`,and the indent is wrong,modified as below:

```
def length(lists):
    a = 0
    answer = ""


    for item in lists:
        x = len(item)
        if x > a:
            a = x
            answer = item
        elif x == a:
            if item not in ans:
                answer = answer + " " + item
    return answer
```

But I think Jonathon Reinhart have provided a better method.

Comment: I did mispell it. i put lists instead of answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I figured out my solution in this way:

```
myList =['hi', 'hello', 'hey','ohman', 'yoloo', 'hello']
def get_longest_strings(myList):
        longest=len(max(myList,key=len))
        for each in myList:
                if(longest==len(each)):
                       #common_result is list to store longest string in list
                       common_result.append(each)
        return common_result
print(common_result)
```

Comment: It is also important that you initialize common_result as common_result = [] before you start adding things to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
def allLongestStrings(inputArray):
    maxLength = len(max(inputArray, key = len))
    
    newArray = []
    
    lengthArray = len(inputArray)
    
    for i in range(lengthArray):
        if(len(inputArray[i])==maxLength):
            newArray.append(inputArray[i])
    return newArray
```