# Find all the strings with max length using max() function

Tags: python, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Longest strings from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964637/longest-strings-from-list)

```
lst = [str1, str2, str3, ...]
max(lst, key=len)
```

This returns only one of the strings with max length. Is there any way to do that without defining another procedure?

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`; that's already the name of the type.

Comment: Also, why don't you want to define another function? If this is something that isn't obvious to you, giving it a name is just going to make it easier to read later.

Comment: @abarnert i just wanted to know if i can add any argument to max() to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
maxlen = len(max(l, key=len)) 
maxlist = [s for s in l if len(s) == maxlen]
```

Comment: This is going to call `max` N times, so the whole thing is unnecessarily O(N^2).

Comment: @abarnert You're right, that's an easy fix (see edit).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get *all* the values with the max length, you probably want to sort the list by length; then you just need to take all the values until the length changes. `itertools` provides multiple ways to do that—`takewhile`, `groupby`, etc. For example:

```
>>> l = ['abc', 'd', 'ef', 'ghi', 'j']
>>> l2 = sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(len, l2)
>>> maxlen, maxvalues = next(groups)
>>> print(maxlen, list(maxvalues))
3, ['abc', 'ghi']
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
>>> maxlen, maxvalues = next(itertools.groupby(len, sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)))
>>> print(maxlen, list(maxvalues))
```

Of course you can always just make two passes over the list if you prefer—first to find the max length, then to find all matching values:

```
>>> maxlen = len(max(l, key=len))
>>> maxvalues = (value for value in l if len(value) == maxlen)
>>> print(maxlen, list(maxvalues))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) is also an option:

```
maxlens = filter(lambda s: len(s)==max(myList, key=len), myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-pass solution, collecting longest-seen-so-far words as they are found.

```
def findLongest(words):
    if not words:
        return []
    worditer = iter(words)
    ret = [next(worditer)]
    cur_len = len(ret[0])
    for wd in worditer:
        len_wd = len(wd)
        if len_wd > cur_len:
            ret = [wd]
            cur_len = len_wd
        else:
            if len_wd == cur_len:
                ret.append(wd)
    return ret
```

Here are the results from some test lists:

```
tests = [
    [],
    "Four score and seven years ago".split(),
    "To be or not to be".split(),
    "Now is the winter of our discontent made glorious summer by this sun of York".split(),
    ]

for test in tests:
    print test
    print findLongest(test)
    print


[]
[]

['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago']
['score', 'seven', 'years']

['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
['not']

['Now', 'is', 'the', 'winter', 'of', 'our', 'discontent', 'made', 'glorious', 'summer', 'by', 'this', 'sun', 'of', 'York']
['discontent']
```